# Looking for an intuitive explanation for a basic combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation for this identity:
$${n \choose k} = \frac{n}{k}{n-1 \choose k-1}$$
for $0 < k \leq n$.

The math adds up, but I can't see *why* it's true. I'd expect that choosing $k$ elements from an $n$-set would be like choosing $k-1$ elements from an $(n-1)$-set, then add an $n$th element to the set, and choose another element from the $n - k + 1$ not-yet-chosen elements. But I guess I'm missing something.

Can anyone provide some intuition?

Comment: The standard combinatorial argument for $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ goes as follows. We want to choose a team of $k$, with designated leader. The left side counts this by choosing $k$ people (there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to do this) and then choosing one of them to be leader ($k$ ways). For the right side, choose the leader first ($n$ ways) and then choose $k-1$ followers.

Comment: Your argument gives four two-element subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$: first take the two one-element subsets of $\{1,2\}$, namely $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, and then take all the ways of adding one more element to each, giving $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.

Comment: I am sorry about the leader-follower example, too militaristic. You want to choose $k$ distinct food items from the $n$ available, keep $1$, give the others to the Food Bank. The rest of the counting is the same.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks, that's an excellent argument. I wish my reputation allowed me to upvote...

Comment: @Gary: Upvotes are nice, but only as an indication that a comment or answer has been found useful. A message to that effect is much better.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94719/proving-k-binomnk-n-binomn-1k-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to see as follows.  Choose the "first" element; there are $n$ ways to do this.  Now choose $k-1$ elements from the remaining $n-1$; there are ${n-1\choose k-1}$ ways to do this.  That gives you $n{n-1\choose k-1}$, but you've overcounted: for example, $\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$ is counted separately from $\lbrace 2,1,3\rbrace$, since your first choice was $1$ in the former case and $2$ in the latter.  So you divide out by the number of distinct ways of selecting a "first" element out of the $k$ that you've chosen; that gives you the additional factor of $1/k$.

Comment: Makes sense (though it took me a while :)). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One can write it like this:
$$k{n \choose k} = n{n-1 \choose k-1}.$$

First you choose $k$ out of $n$; then you choose one of the $k$ to be the leader.  There are $\binom nk$ ways to make the first choice, and then $k$ ways to make the second choice.  That's the left side of the identity.

Alternatively, first you choose one of the $n$ to be the leader; then you choose $k-1$ of the remaining $n-1$ to be the others in the group of $k$.  That's the right side of the identity.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to $${n\choose r}{r\choose 1}={n\choose 1}{n-1\choose r-1}$$