# How do I prove that $\binom{n}{k} \cdot k=n \cdot \small\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How do I prove that
$$
{n\choose k}*k=n*{n-1\choose k-1}
$$
Wolfram says that it's right, but I'm stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Proving $k \binom{n}{k} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94719/) (not speaking of Wikipedia etc)

Comment: See also [«intuitive explanation»](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97958/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more "combinatorial proof":
suppose you want to select a team of $k$ people from a group of $n$ people and you also want to choose a captain for the team.
You can do this in two ways:

1. Choose the $k$ people out of $n$ (${n\choose k}$ choices) and select which of these k people is the captain ($k$ choices). Hence in total ${n\choose k}*k$.
2. Choose a captain ($n$ choices) and then select $k-1$ people from the remaining $n-1$ people (${n-1 \choose k-1}$ choices) to be part of the team. Hence in total $n*{n-1 \choose k-1}$.

Therefore ${n\choose k}*k=n*{n-1\choose k-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing out the definitions using factorials.

Answer (score 2):

Come back to the definition.

$${n\choose k}\times k=\frac{n!\times k}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n\times (n-1)!}{(k-1)!((n-1)-(k-1))!}=n\times {n-1\choose k-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have a group of $n$ people. We want to choose a committee of $k$ people, and a committee Chair. We count the number of ways to do this in two different ways.

**Way 1:** Choose $k$ people, then choose $1$ of these to be Chair. The $k$ people can be chosen in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways, and for each such choice, the Chair can be chosen in $\binom{k}{1}$, that is, $k$ ways, for a total of $k\binom{n}{k}$ ways.

**Way 2:** We can choose the Chair in $\binom{n}{1}$, that is, $n$ ways. For each of these ways, there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose the remaining $k-1$ people to join her on the committee, for a total of $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Combinatorial Proof**

Observe that the LHS $\binom{n}{k}k$ is the number of ways of choosing a set of $k$ objects from $n$ objects and then one object within this set. This is equivalent to the number of ways to choose one object from a set of $n$ objects and then $k-1$ objects from the remaining $n-1$ objects that is the RHS $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

*Note* this relation is known as *Absorbtion property*