# How to prove that $(n+1)\binom{n}{k}=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How to prove that for the integers $k,n$ where $k \leq n$ the following holds:
$$(n+1)\binom{n}{k}=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Comment: As an aside, this site uses MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to typeset equations.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn more.  `$(n+1)\binom{n}{k}=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$` produces $(n+1)\binom{n}{k}=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.  You can rightclick people's formulae and select "Show Math As>TeX Commands" to see how they have typed it as well.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94719/proving-k-binomnk-n-binomn-1k-1), this closed [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628213/how-do-i-prove-that-binomnk-cdot-k-n-cdot-small-binomn-1k-1?rq=1) and Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align*}&(n+1)\binom nk=(n+1)\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\{}\\&(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}=(k+1)\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}\end{align*}$$

Check carefully both expressions above and convince yourself they're they same. Take into account that

$$m!(m+1)=(m+1)!$$

Answer (score 5):

For a combinatorial proof of the above property:

Suppose you start with $n+1$ students in a classroom.  The teacher wants to create a group of students with a leader so that they work on a special assignment together.  The special group will be of size $k+1$ (with $k$ followers and $1$ leader).

Count how many ways there are to accomplish this in two ways:

- Pick the leader of the group first followed by picking the $k$ followers from the remaining $n$ students.  ($n+1$ ways to pick the leader, $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to pick the followers for a total of $(n+1)\binom{n}{k}$ ways to create the group)
- Pick all of the members of the group first and then after picking the members, select one of them to be the leader.  ($\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ ways to pick the members of the group, and then $k+1$ ways to pick one of the group members to lead for a total of $(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ ways to create the group)

By principles, if two expressions enumerate the same situation, they must be equal.  Hence:
$$(n+1)\binom{n}{k}=(k+1)\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Comment: Very nice illustration !