# How to show $2^{-13}\sum ^{13}_{n=0}12n\begin{pmatrix} 13 \\ n \end{pmatrix}$ = $2^{-14}\left( 12.13\right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show $\sum ^{13}_{n=0}12n\begin{pmatrix} 13 \\ n \end{pmatrix}$ = $2^{12}\left( 12.13\right) $

I really do not know how to start with this. I guess it amounts to showing $\sum ^{N}_{k=0}k\begin{pmatrix} N \\ k \end{pmatrix}=2^{N-1}N$

I know $\sum ^{N}_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix} N \\ k \end{pmatrix}=2^{N}$ so i guess differentiating both sides w.r N, but I don't se ehow the left hand side works.

Comment: binomial theorem and $\binom{N}{k} = \binom{N}{N-k}$.

Comment: Your title and your question are different - the title (i.e. $2^{-13}\sum(\ldots)=2^{-14}(12\cdot 13)$) is clearly wrong (multiply by $2^{13}$, divide by $12$ and just compare a couple of terms) so I presume you just mean $2^{-1}$ on the RHS?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to show what you mention :

We have

$$ k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1} $$

by counting or calculus.

Then re-index you sum and you win !

Comment: ah thank you, I can see it with that identity now, and can see how it works when write it out. I still don't get how you do it with calculus.

Comment: You may use series expansion of ( 1+x)^n as binomial sum,Then use calculus.

Comment: ok @AshPd, I see how it could work, $\left( 1+x\right) ^{n}=\sum ^{n}_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}x^{k}$, d/dx(_) of both sides $\Leftrightarrow$ $n\left( 1+x\right) ^{n-1}$ =$\sum ^{n}_{k=0}k\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}x^{k-1}$ . So I am left with $\sum ^{n-1}_{k=1}n\begin{pmatrix} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{pmatrix}x^{k-1}$ = $\sum ^{n}_{k=0}k\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}x^{k-1}$. I cannot get the summation indexes to match up , I think this has something to do with the first differentiation and that the $x^{-1}$ term should not be present

Answer (score 0):

You can show by calculus the previous identity with :

**Direct Calculus Method**

$$ k\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{k\prod_{i=n-k+1}^ni}{\prod_{i=1}^ki}=\dfrac{n\prod_{i=n-k+1}^{n-1}i}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}i}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1} $$

Comment: Ok, I see that, thats what i thought you meant by counting, I don't see how that is calculus.

Comment: Counting is with combinatoric. I can provide you a proof

Comment: I am grateful for the help for solving the actual question! So I apologise, as I am not trying to be facetious and feel free to ignore, because this s such a non-consequential issue.
But I don’t see how the above is calculus. I can see that using  $\left( 1+x\right) ^{n}=\sum ^{n}_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}x^{k}$  as @AshPd suggests, and differentiating both sides is calculus. Whilst the above seems combinatorial, and just consists of changing indices.

Comment: I give you the link of the answer I gave on the calculs proofs

Comment: This is combinatoric : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2828144/564189

Comment: @Tinatim To see the difference between calculus and combinatoric : Calculus is more quantitative (You use rules of calculus) . Combinatoric is more qualitative , summoning balls, players, set more based on - we understand it make that .

Comment: You furthermore use bijection prooves to clearly justify your combinatoric development.